# Seemingly trivial MySQL query with if statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got two fields called T1 and T2 defined as double. I'd like to set T3 with the following conditions:

```
If T1 & T2 >0 then T3=(T1+T2)/2
If T1==0 then T3=T2
if T2==0 then T3=T1
if T1==0 & T2==0, T3=-9999
```

I have no idea how to include multiple if statements in the query.

Comment: I don't think you need my table structure to answer this but let me know if you do.

Comment: Is this an `UPDATE` query or a `SELECT` query that you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET t3 = CASE 
              WHEN t1 + t2 > 0 THEN (t1 + t2)/2.0
              WHEN t1 + t2 = 0 THEN -9999
              WHEN t1 = 0 THEN t2
              WHEN t2 = 0 THEN t1
            END
```

What if t1 + t2 is less than zero?

Comment: T1 or T2 can never be less than zero (at least not in the data I received). Many thanks OMG Ponies.